# What does this C++ pointer syntax mean?

Tags: c++, pointers

Say `data`is a direct pointer to the memory array used by a vector.

What then, does `&data[index]` mean?

I'm guessing `data[index]` is a pointer to the particular element of the array at position `index`, but then is `&data[index]`the address of that pointer?

Comment: If `data` points at the "memory array used by a vector", it points at the first element of that vector.   `data[index]` is then (a reference to NOT a pointer to) the `index`th element of the vector with zero-based indexing  (e.g. if `index` is `0` then `data[index]` is the first element of the vector, if `index` is `9` then `data[index]` is the tenth element of the vector).  The preceding assumes the vector has ten or more elements - if that assumption is untrue, then evaluating the expression `data[index]` gives undefined behaviour.    `&data[index]` is the address of `data[index]`.

Comment: Your guess is wrong. `data[index]` is the element at position `index`, not a pointer to it. `&data[index]` is the pointer.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_subscript_operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with working out the types.

Suppose `data` is a `T*`; a pointer to the first element of an array of `T`.
Then `data[index]` is a `T`, and that `T` is an element of the array.
And since `data[index]` is a `T`, `&data[index]` is a `T*`; it is a pointer to the array element `data[index]`.

Also, if `data` is a pointer, `data[index]` is equivalent to `*(data + index)`, so `&data[index]` is equivalent to `&*(data + index)`, and the `&*` cancel each other out and you're left with `&data[index] == data + index`.

Answer (score 1):

`&x` is the address of `x`. `x` can be the element in an array. If `data` is a vectors `data()` (a pointer to first element of the vectors internal array) then `data[index]` is the element at index `index` of that vector.

Yes, `&data[index]` is a pointer to element at index `index` of the vector.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  "data" itself isn't a vector though - it is what you get from vec.data() where vec is the vector.

Comment: @VarunJain I didnt say that `data` is a vector. Added clarification

Comment: Sorry I want to upvote this answer but I don't have enough reputation :(

Answer (score 1):

The subscript `operator[]` has **higher precedence** than the address of `operator&`. Thus, due to **operator precedence** `&data[index]` is equivalent to(*grouped as*):

```
&(data[index]) //this is equivalent to the expression &data[index]
```

which means that the above is a pointer to an element at index `index` of the array. This is because `data[index]` gives us the element at index `index` so applying the address of operator `&` will give us a *pointer to that element*.

Comment: Sorry I want to upvote this answer but I don't have enough reputation :(